# is a hashed uuid4 a good csrf token?

Tags: token, csrf, uuid, entropy

Is this a good csrf token? Does it have enough entropy, or are there parts that are easily guessable and could reduce the entropy, like the time of the request?

An example python implementation would b

```
token = hashlib.sha256(str(uuid.uuid4())).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uuid v4 has 122 random bits (of a possible 128) so, yes, it should be fine as a CSRF token.

(BTW, does hashing this accomplish anything?  It's not really doing much other than shuffling random bits around.)

Comment: I'm not sure how much is revealed about a system by exposing the uuid4, so I was hashing that to obscure any details that might be revealed.

Comment: then don't bother with the hash.  The 6 non-random bits are for the uuid variant and version as per rfc4122, and are the same for all v4 uuids; they don't reveal anything about your system.

Comment: I'm doing something similar. The UUIDv4 is the sessionID (implemented as a HttpOnly cookie), the session's antiCSRF token is sha256(sessionID), keeps things simple & doesn't expose the sessionID to javascript.